# MYSQL : null behavior against integer check

Tags: mysql, null

Lets say i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  )
```

and fill it with this record:

```
INSERT INTO offers (status) VALUES (null);
```

now  run this query :

```
DELETE FROM offers WHERE STATUS <> 3
```

I'm expecting the latest record get removed from table but it doesn't.why? and whats the correct way to solve such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in [MySQL's documentation about NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html). The integer comparison you are doing does not satisfy `NULL` value. `NULL` is not treated as a value, it signifies the absence of one. If you want to delete those rows you have to say

```
DELETE FROM offers WHERE status <> 3 OR status IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL the value `NULL` is *very special*!  Pretty much *any* expression that has a `NULL` value in it will evaluate to `NULL`.  That means that when you do the `STATUS<>3`, if `STATUS` is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`, which when used directly as a truth value is false.  So, the expression `WHERE STATUS <> 3` selects rows that *have a value other than 3*.  Rows with the value 3 and rows with no value (i.e. `NULL`) will *not* be selected.  The only time a comparison of a variable that's `NULL` can be true is if you use the `IS NULL` comparison, or related special constructs.  You probably want to review the relevant sections of the manual, if you actually want to use `NULL` in a constructive fashion.

Answer (score 0):

null is not a string it is a keyword in mysql, so use:-

```
DELETE FROM offers WHERE STATUS is null
```